# Almost sure convergence of a series with a given distribution

Tags: probability

I have a sequence $\{X_{n}\}$ of independent random variables with law
\begin{equation} P\left(X_{n}=-n^{2}\right)=\frac{1}{n^{2}} ; \quad \quad P\left(X_{n}=\frac{n^{2}}{n^{2}-1}\right)=1-\frac{1}{n^{2}}. 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}S_{n}=X_{1}+...+X_{n}
\end{equation}
I have to prove that $\frac{S_{n}}{n} \to 1 \quad a.s. \quad $
Can anyone help me? I have already tried in different ways

Answer (score 1):

Show that $X_n\to 1$ a.s using Borel Cantelli and apply [stolz-cesaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) to deduce the result